# when i delete localStorage in setInterval

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
 mounted(){
        setInterval(()=>{
          if(localStorage.isverify){
            alert(localStorage.isverify)
              delete localStorage.isverify
                this.datalistp = 1;
                this.datalist = [];
                this.loadRecommend();
             return;
          }
        },2000)
```

when i use this function in vue.js
the alert() in the function still alert in this page,after delete localStorage.isverify

Comment: are you sure nobody is setting the value back

Comment: Cannot reproduce, this code should work.

Comment: The missing `;` at the end of the line ?

Comment: Use proper localStorage documented methods

Comment: I think you need to show us more of your code. This works; something else is modifying `localStorage`. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).